# Python - Mac os x terminal - subdirectories - limit of 255 thousand files?

Tags: python, macos, file, copy

I am trying to copy over 350 thousand text files from some folders to some other folders, using the following code in Python, on a Mac OS X terminal:

```
subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk("/folders/")]
for subdir in subdirs:                                                                                          
    files = os.walk(subdir).next()[2] 
    for f in files:
        if ".txt" in f:
            with open(subdir + "/" + f) as inputfile:
                if not os.path.exists("/folder/"+year+"/"):
                    os.makedirs("/folder/"+year+"/")
                print "This should be true orelse there will be no copy :  ", os.path.isfile(subdir + "/" + f)     
                if os.path.isfile(subdir + "/" + f):       
                    shutil.copy(subdir + "/" + f, "/folder_to_copy_to/"+year+"/"+f)
```

Although there are over 350 thousand files in these folders, only 255 thousand files get copied... I suppose there is some limit to the commands that locate the files? That has to do with the OS ? Is there some way to increase this limit so that all files get copied correctly?

Comment: Which files are missing? Does it seem random, or is there a pattern?

Comment: How can I check which files are missing? When I use a counter of the files it reaches, it seems to get to 350 thousand files, but only 255 thousand files get moved..

Comment: Try this in Terminal to count the files... `find /folders -type f | wc -l`

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: I right click the two folders, click "Get Info", from where I see that one of which has 377 thousand files, and the other 255 thousand files.

Comment: Do they all have `.txt` in their names?

Comment: Just to note, `Cmd-I` gives you info about many things in OS X.

Comment: Peter, they have .txt, orelse they would not pass the if and the counter would not increase..

Comment: I ran the two following commands `find folders/ -name "*.txt" | wc -l
  340983`
`find folders_to_move_to/ -name "*.txt" | wc -l
  255551`

Comment: Why do you open the file and then not use it? It would fail if it didn't exist, and then all the checks you do would never happen, anyway.

Comment: I open it because I check the year (getting it from inside the txt file) so that I move it in the appropriate folder

Comment: This isn't the actual code, e.g. `folder_to_copy_to`.

Comment: Yes I changed that, no reason to show my computer name and my real name etc. you can see that there is a folder I get the files from, and a folder I move the files to

Comment: what are you using `files = os.walk(subdir).next()[2]`

Comment: because there are files inside subdirectories...

Comment: You can also have up to  2.1 billion  files in a directory on mac osx https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201711

Comment: Any idea why I have this problem then ?

Comment: Two thoughts... 1) I presume you `close()` the files you open and are not running into a limit of open files? 2) How about adding some status checking after calling functions to see if they worked or not?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, `with` closes the files for you so there is no need to call close

Comment: @adrCoder,  so you just want to copy all txt files to a single folder or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: In the beginning, I have all files inside subdirectories, based on some identifier (some name). Then, I want to move the txt files in other directories, based on which year they belong to. The year they belong to is found by some line in each text file which states which year they belong to.

Comment: Add your full code to pastebin, also `for root, sub, files in os.walk("/folders/"):` would be a lot more readable than what you are doing with the list come and next

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UH5MtYA7

Comment: Are all the files you want to copy readable by your user?

Comment: I have admin account so I suppose yes